# Can I create a separate custom Person Object in Salesforce/SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-object

Leads and Contacts are special objects. They are treated differently by the system.

I need a custom one.

Can I use a separate RecordType? Yes, this is perfect except that it doesn't help with certain restrictions around separation of data that have been set.

If I have a new object called PeopleNotContacts__c with name, email, DoB... How can I enter these as a prospect to send them an email?

Issues:

- Leads are being used to store a very specific type of Persons. This
  data is reserved for a few user types (profiles).
- Contacts are also used for a very specific set of Persons. Person Alpha may appear in both Leads and Contacts. The data is also reserved to a few user
  types (profiles)
- Then we have employees. The data in Employee is reserved for specific users. We are going to be sending these Persons emails using SFMC. Person Alpha may appear in Leads, Contacts and Employees. Each data is distinct and separate.

I am currently skinning Employees as a RecordType of Contact but was wondering if there is a different way to go.

Comment: You really should start with a problem statement rather than diving into a solution.

Comment: @identigral I added some context

Comment: Ignoring SFMC, here's a previous question that addresses this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3541/what-is-the-downside-to-using-a-custom-object-instead-of-contact-for-people-base

Comment: @identigral Thank you for finding that. I tried but wasn't looking for the correct thing. Perfect response from zachelrath